# Microsoft snippet waiting for a System.Threading.Thread to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, wait

I was looking at the Microsoft MSDN reference page regarding the modifier "volatile", and was a little unsure as to the way in which the snippet they provided, waited for a thread to complete execution.

I know it is only example code, and that the thread completed very quickly, but I believe that the code below is not very good for developers trying to understand threading.

I believe Microsoft have actually presented a code snippet which will introduce a "tight-loop" in the code. Now I appreciate that it will not affect this code snippet (that much), but if a developer takes this code and tries to use it for some multi-threaded code that is a little more intensive, I would presume the "tight-loop" issue would arise?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Test
{
   public static int result;   
   public static volatile bool finished;
   static void Thread2() {
      result = 143;    
      finished = true; 
   }
   static void Main() {
      finished = false;
      // Run Thread2() in a new thread
      new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2)).Start();
      // Wait for Thread2 to signal that it has a result by setting
      // finished to true.
      for (;;) {
         if (finished) {
            Console.WriteLine("result = {0}", result);
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Snippet reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645755(v=vs.71).aspx

What would be the better way to wait for the thread to finish, in the example above, which would not introduce this "tight-loop" situation?

Or, will a "tight-loop" not actually be introduced at all?

Please note, that the purpose of the snippet is to demonstrate the "volatile" keyword, so using a Thread.Join() would take the snippet out of context I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet doesn't illustrate how to wait, this just illustrates access to a `volatile` field from different threads.

To wait for your background thread simply, you can use this snippet:

```
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                              {
                                   // do your stuff
                                   ((AutoResetEvent)o).Set();
                              }, autoEvent);
autoEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use a ManualResetEvent. As the worker thread does not start again after the waiting thread has been released.

Comment: @MartinBrown Can you explain how this can happen?

Comment: This is nice. I will have to read up on what the difference is between the Manual and AutoResetEvent.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan The AutoResetEvent, as its name implies, resets itself when it has released a single waiting thread. If there was two threads waiting on the autoEvent (I know there isn't in this code) using an AutoResetEvent would mean the second thread would never see that the worker thread had finished. A ManualResetEvent releases all waiting threads when it is signalled and does not reset unless told to do so. This would mean that if there were two or more waiting threads that all of them would see that the worker thread had finished.

Comment: @MartinBrown I know how they works, thanks. But in the current context, as you noticed, there are no difference.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan the current context is giving people an example they can follow when writing their own solutions. As such it would be better to give the more flexible solution as we don't know what other people might be using it for.

Answer (score 1):

As you say the best way to wait for a thread to finish would be to use [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) or an ManualResetEventSlim event however neither of these would require a [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) bool.

It would be possible to use the code in the example by adding a call to [Thread.SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx) in the loop. This would help to prevent processor starvation. In version 4 of .Net Microsoft added a struct called [SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) that can be used more effectivly.

There is more information about this in ["Threading in C#" by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinLock_and_SpinWait)

Comment: Thread.SpinWait has actually answered another of my questions, so thank you. I assume SpinWait will stop the warning message of a deadlock appearing for long threads that run?